# Problem selecting update sources in GUI (Software & Updates - Updates)

Tags: settings, updates, sources

In "Software & Updates - Updates" all look un-checked. But I know they are in fact all enabled:

[image]

When trying to check them, I cannot, as they are immediately un-checked.

It looks like so:

[image]

For higher detail see [this video](https://plus.google.com/+CipricusCipriq/posts/hB7EBjwWnbc?pid=6142868495647820962&oid=109655288210924730560). (The problem on the update errors reported along with the video on elementary Google+ and also present at the beginning at the video is now outdated/solved; I am referring to what happens after 0:15.)

What happens in fact is that **each click there creates a duplicate (for the recommended, unsupported and important updates)** in "Software & Updates - Other software".

I have solved this just by removing those sources added there in this way so that only one entry is left there for each type.

[image]

After that, all updates and sources are fine. But the problem with the "Software & Updates - Updates" check-boxes is still there.

Those check-boxes under "Software & Updates - Updates" still looks un-checked and I have to avoid touching them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug that has been reported before, [Launchpad: in software source you can't select the updates](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1176595) . Please mark it as "yes , it affects me" and provide more informations if it's needed, or put a bounty on it to attract some developers to fix it.

Comment: did that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1176595/comments/3