# Recent change in elementary OS repository structure?

Tags: release-freya, updates, ppa

Has there be in recent time (mor exactly on 4 oct 2015) a change to the structure of the elementary OS repository in ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/ changing URL pattern from .../freya/... to .../trusty/...?

Update: Meanwhile I got so much frustrated with trying to fix problems with elementary OS that I made a totally new install and still did run into the problem with broken update links for ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/freya/... so I edited elementary.list and patches.list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ into the .../trusty/... pattern. Result: No more errors on apt-get update and apt-get distro-upgrade but after restarting I do not get the elementary "e" logo on booting the system. I do not know if this is only a cosmetic problem or if it is a symptom that I lost something important from elementary OS. The desktop still looks and feels like elementary OS.

Background of my question:

I installed this week elementary Os from a fresh download of the live-version named elementaryos-stable-0.3.1-amd64.20150903.iso and run into problems with apt-get update giving me " 404  Not Found" error messages on fetching data from URLs like  http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/freya/main/binary-amd64/Packages . Entering that URL into a Browser the site does not exist. What I found was a working URL: http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Looking further into the repository I found two new folders in http:  ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/dists/ created on 4 Oct 2015: "devel" and "trusty". Now I wonder if the repository structure has been changed from hard-coding the elementary OS distribution-version code-names like "luna", "freya",... into one fix name for the next version development trunk (devel) and a trunk with the code-name of the ubuntu LTS-version on that the current stable elementary-os version is based on (trusty). (Maybe this makes it easier to install elementary as Desktop Environment on top of an existing Ubuntu installation.)

That could explain why the current elementary-distro 0.3.1 from 3 sep 2015 does not know about the new URL and fails to update. If so, I could rename the respective URLs in my local /etc/apt/sources.list file from .../freya/... to .../trusty/... and it should work. But as long as I am not shure that I am right on my guess about the change in repository structure I do not want to mess up my elementary OS installation totally by fetching wrong update lists.

You can find more information on my update problem in this question: [Software update fails to work](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3039/software-update-fails-to-work/3044#3044)

Thanks for any advice
Olaf

Note: I could not write all URLs correctly because the forum system allows only for max. of 2 working URls in my posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it on good authority from within elementary that no repository should ever contain `luna`, `freya`, or `loki`. If your `sources.list` ever contained that, they were incorrect, and should be changed to `precise`, `trusty`, and `wily` respectively. As for the changes to the repositories, those are likely unrelated changes to the build structure, and nothing to do with this.

Comment: thanks! I already tried the changes and apt-get update/upgrade seems to run smoothly. So it seems to be a bug in the freya 0.3.1 distribution to set the wrong update path in elementary.list and patches.list